# No module named requests but satisfied on RP OS 64bit

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pihole

Occasionally my PiHole goes down and I'm unavailable to resolve any sites, it just did it the other day for hours before I noticed.

I'm trying to run this to catch the times that I miss it so it doesn't mess up anything for anyone else on the network.

For some reason, it's telling me on line 1, no module named Requests when I already have it.

Verified by running `pip show requests` and it shows version 2.25.1, installed using `sudo pip install requests`.

I'm running Python 2.7.18. I have another Pi I tested it on which doesn't seem to show any problems but I have omv installed on it so I couldn't test with Pihole without fear of breaking something.

Any advice on how to get the code working? Thanks.

In the end I'm planning to have a cronjob that will start on reboot, launch tmux and run this.

Edit:
It looks like I already had `requests` installed as a dependency for another program.

The location is
`/home/usr/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

```
import requests
import subprocess
import time

def check_reachability(url):
  try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
      return True
    else:
      return False
  except:
    return False

def reboot_pihole():
  subprocess.run(["pihole", "restartdns"])

while True:
  reachable = check_reachability("htts://google.com")
  if not reachable:
    reboot_pihole()
  time.sleep(60) # check every 60 seconds
```

Comment: "No module named requests" isn't a problem caused by your code, so just showing the code to your application doesn't help us solve it. We need to know _how you installed `requests`_, _where_ it's installed, and how the `sys.path` active when it can be found compares with the one that's active when it can't.

Comment: (If you used a `pip` tied to one version of Python, but then a `python` executable from another, that's a common way to get this problem; likewise installing into a virtualenv but trying to run against a system interpreter or the inverse; but right now the question has no details relevant to detecting any of those scenarios. See [mre] guidelines: We want the _shortest possible_ code or set of steps we can use to cause the same problem to happen somewhere we can see it ourselves).

Comment: BTW, Python 2.x is out-of-support; you should really try to move to Python 3. (And if the copy of `pip` you ran was installing packages for a Python 3 interpreter rather than for your Python 2.7.18, that would explain the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just running

```
python3 program.py
```

instead of

```
python program.py
```

Edit: The program was written for Python 3 when I have both Python 2.7 and 3 installed.